# ReactJS mobx - does not update observable array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

If you have an `observable` list in your store:

```
@obserable public Claimslist: IClaim[] = [];
```

where `IClaim` is an interface, `claims` is an array of `IClaim` objects

`IClaim` contains a varaible in its object called `moveOutDate`
Each claim object has `id` variable.

And now you want to update or get that variable by the `claim` id

So you have 2 functions:

**Get**

```
  /**
   * Gets the moveOutDate of a claim by claim ID
   */
  @action getMoveOutDateById = (id: string) => {
    // Get the claim by id
    const claim = this.Claimslist.find((element: IClaim) => element.id === sessionStorage.getItem('claim-id'));
    if (claim) {
      if (!claim.moveOutDate) {
        return undefined;
      }
      return moment(new Date(claim.moveOutDate)).toDate();
    }

    return undefined;
  }
```

**Set**

```
  /**
   * Sets moveOutDate in claim by claim ID
   */
  @action public setMoveOutDate = (id: string, date: Date) => {
    const claim = this.Claimslist.find((element: IClaim) => element.id === id);
    if (claim) {
      claim.moveOutDate = date.toString();
    }
  }
```

Okey, but now when you use `getMoveOutDateById` at first in your `render` it works and renders the date, but once you call `setMoveOutDate` `onUpdate` of the date component, the render won't update, but the store will update and you can only see changes if you refresh the page.

Now I managed to solve it, by doing:

```
this.Claimslist = this.Claimslist.slice();
```

and adding an hidden input of Claimslist:

```
const {Claimslist} = this.props.claimsStore;
```

and

```
<input type="hidden" value={Claimslist} />
```

Why does it happen, if the whole object is `obserable` and is wrapped with `@action` why doesn't it change without using `slice()` and having an hidden input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mobx `observable` only observes shallow values. Meaning lets say I have `@observable claims[]` then `claims[0] = something` will trigger an update but `claims[0].foo = bar` will not [(docs)](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observable.html). To fix this you need to make `foo` also observable by adding `@observable foo` on `claim` object.

Consider the following example. Notice the difference between `Claim1` and `Claim2`. The components are exactly same yet `ClaimView2` will update and `ClaimView1` will not. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hyweu2?file=index.tsx)

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { observable, action } from "mobx";
import { observer } from "mobx-react";

class Claim1 {
  moveOutDate: Date;
  constructor() {
    this.moveOutDate = new Date();
  }
}

@observer
class ClaimsView1 extends React.Component {
  @observable claims: Claim1[] = [
    new Claim1(),
    new Claim1()
  ];

  @action.bound
  updateClaims(){
    this.claims.forEach(claim => {
      claim.moveOutDate = new Date();
    })
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <pre>
        {"ClaimsView1 = \n" + JSON.stringify(this.claims, null, "  ")}
      </pre>
      <button onClick={this.updateClaims}> Update </button>
    </div>
  }
}


class Claim2 {
  @observable moveOutDate: Date;
  constructor() {
    this.moveOutDate = new Date();
  }
}

@observer
class ClaimsView2 extends React.Component {
  @observable claims: Claim2[] = [
    new Claim2(),
    new Claim2()
  ];

  @action.bound
  updateClaims(){
    this.claims.forEach(claim => {
      claim.moveOutDate = new Date();
    })
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <pre>
        {"ClaimsView2 = \n" + JSON.stringify(this.claims, null, "  ")}
      </pre>
      <button onClick={this.updateClaims}> Update </button>
    </div>
  }
}

render(
  <>
    <ClaimsView1 />
    <ClaimsView2 />
  </>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

### Update:

Here's a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-2j8yyu?file=index.tsx) for the solution I gave in the comments

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { observable, action } from "mobx";
import { observer } from "mobx-react";

interface IClaim {
  moveOutDate: Date;
}

@observer
class ClaimsView extends React.Component<{claims: IClaim[]}> {
  @observable claims: IClaim[] = this.props.claims.map(claim => observable(claim))

  updateClaims = () => {
    this.claims.forEach(claim => {
      claim.moveOutDate = new Date();
    })
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <pre>
        {"claims = \n" + JSON.stringify(this.claims, null, "  ")}
      </pre>
      <button onClick={this.updateClaims}> Update </button>
    </div>
  }
}


render(
  <ClaimsView claims={[
    { moveOutDate: new Date() },
    { moveOutDate: new Date() }
  ]} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: But IClaim is an interface, and you can't do that in an interface?

Comment: @Ben You still can make each property observable by passing the object of interface `IClaim` to the observable decorator/function and then pushing it in the array. [docs](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/object.html)

Comment: @Ben and ofc if you already have the array filled then you can map over it  with `observable` function and reassign the array.

Comment: @Ben I have updated the answer with a demo implementing the solution in case of interfaces. Please check it out.

Comment: Hi thanks! But you have to understand that I use an interface that have optional properties e.g variable?: string; so you cant do that i think

Comment: @Ben what makes you think  you can't do that? replace `interface IClaim { moveOutDate: Date }` with `interface IClaim { moveOutDate: Date, foo?: string }` and it will still work. Also Welcome!

Comment: but can you do that obseravble on optional variables too?

Comment: @Ben Yes. Here's a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-guzsyz?file=index.tsx). I guess this is what you wanted, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190437/discussion-between-ben-beri-and-devansh-j).

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly the same, missing @observable, it will be the same if:

```
class Claim1 {
  @observable moveOutDate: Date;
...
```